# Grep ^ and $ at the same time

Tags: grep

I'm, trying to use grep with a ^ and $ at the same time but for some reason that does not work. If I type

```
grep '^s.*e' german.dic
```

I get a lots of words starting with `s` and having an `e` somewhere. A snippet from the output

```
szientistischer
szientistisches
szintigraphische
szintigraphischem
szintigraphischen
szintigraphischer
szintigraphisches
```

So there is a word 'szintigraphische', which has an e at the end of the line. What I would expect now is that if I typed

```
grep '^s.*e$' german.dic
```

that I would at least get that result. However, the resultset is empty. How should I write a correct regexp to find all words starting with an `s` and ending with an `e`?

Comment: Are you sure the command did not work? I checked and the output was szintigraphische!

Comment: Ditto coffeMug.  I literally cut n' pasted your snippet into a file, then cut and pasted your `grep '^s.*e$'` and it output 'szintigraphische' as it should.  *Maybe there is extra whitespace at the end of the line in file?*

Comment: You can use this `'^s.*e\s*$'` to skip white spaces if there are any. `\s*` tells grep to ignore white spaces.

Comment: Yep, coffeMug,  it was indeed whitespace ! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have some white spaces on the end of the 3rd line.
To skip those you can modify your command as follows:

```
grep '^s.*e\s*$' german.dic
```

`\s*` tells grep to include white spaces (tab/space/cr/lf) if there are any at the end of the current line.

Comment: Note that although `\s` is supported in grep (GNU grep 2.21 here), it's not documented, so using `[[:space:]]` would be safer.

Comment: It is likely that the file they are working with (were, 7+ years ago) was a Windows/DOS text file with carriage return characters at the end of each line. The correct course of action would then be to convert the `german.dic` file to a Unix text file using `dos2unix`.